# Plugin for user comments, star ratings, badge, activity

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I'm currently running a review website that I would like to open to readers.

In short, readers would subscribe and they would be able to rate products (custom post types), rate brands (custom post types too), and gain badges for the number of reviews, if they are facebook/instagram fans, etc.

A very satisfactory outcome would look like this https://demooz.com/fr/u/titipixote (user page - not my website).

What plugin would you recommend to organize this?

Thank you very much,
Ntel

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you may need a few plugins to get the job done.

https://www.mycred.me/ - Points management system to earn badges.
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/ - User Reviews plugin